# Angular nesting components with data

Tags: angular, vue.js

I'm trying to nest multiple components like below. 
My goal is to inject the user data into the user-item component without writing the item component inside the list component.

**App-Component**

```
<app-user-list>
    <app-user-item></app-user-item>
</app-user-list>
```

**User-List-Component**

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let user of users">           
       ???
    </div>
</div>
```

**User-Item_component**

```
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">{{ user.name }}</h5>
    </div>
```

Comment: so you are trying to pass the data from user-list to user-item using your @Input?

Comment: `<ng-content>` is for static content projection. Try using `@ContentChildren` and `QueryList`.

Comment: Yes, but from OUTSIDE of the user-list component. so a simple bind wont work. I believe..

Comment: Can you please make a small demo to understand your requirement.

Comment: I edited my question. Hopefully its more clear now. I dont think a demo would help as it wouldnt work if I made it :P

Comment: @Macdows `without writing the item component` means, you can write component inside `*ngFor` right!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy if you provide `TemplateRef` to `UserListComponent`.

**app.component.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <app-user-list>
        <ng-template let-item>
            <app-user-item [user]="item"></app-user-item>
        </ng-template>
    </app-user-list>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**user-list.component.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  template: `
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let user of users; template: template"></div>
  `
})
export class UserListComponent {
  users = [
    {
      name: 'User 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'User 2'
    }
  ];

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**user-item.component.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-item',
  template: `
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">{{ user.name }}</h2>
    </div>
  `
})
export class UserItemComponent {
  @Input() user: any;
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/pgZbwLvxPuK7LrwhVWud?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&layout=1)**

Comment: This is exactly what I meant! Thanks.